# openpyxl: chart.title = "Chart Heading" not functional. How do I add the heading to a scatter chart?

Tags: openpyxl

I'm using Python 3.6.3 and openpyxl 2.5.4

I wrote some code and noticed that setting my chart title with `chart.title = "Test Heading"` does nothing.  As a sanity check I copied and running the [example from here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/scatter.html):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    ScatterChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = [
    ['Size', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2'],
    [2, 40, 30],
    [3, 40, 25],
    [4, 50, 30],
    [5, 30, 25],
    [6, 25, 35],
    [7, 20, 40],
]

for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)

chart = ScatterChart()
chart.title = "Scatter Chart"
chart.style = 13
chart.x_axis.title = 'Size'
chart.y_axis.title = 'Percentage'

xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
for i in range(2, 4):
    values = Reference(ws, min_col=i, min_row=1, max_row=7)
    series = Series(values, xvalues, title_from_data=True)
    chart.series.append(series)

ws.add_chart(chart, "A10")

wb.save("scatter.xlsx")
```

**Sadly the title in my sample output is still missing:**
[image]

Oddly, changing `title_from_data=True` to `title_from_data=False` also seems to have no effect on the contents of the chart.

Comment: The problem persists even with an update to openpyxl 2.5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks very much like a bug in the application you're using to view the file, which I suspect is LibreOffice.

Comment: I verified this via google docs and filed [bug 119138](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119138)